# When quotient module become a direct summand?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

let $M$ be a $R$- module and $N$ be a submodule of $N$. If $L$ be another module such that $L \cong M/N$  when we could say $L \cong M \oplus N$.?
What if we put  $N = ker\varphi$ where  $\varphi : M \rightarrow L$.

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to this question - there are whole cohomology theories devoted to its answer! The answer to your last question is a definite no. For example, there is a $\mathbb Z$-module map $\varphi\colon\mathbb Z/4\to\mathbb Z/2$ with kernel $\mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: if $\varphi (1) =0$ then $\varphi =0$.  How the kernel can contain $1$?,

Comment: The kernel is $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

This is the same thing as asking

> When does the [exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) $0\to N\to M\to L\to 0$ split?

The [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) is the standard result in basic homological algebra that characterizes when this happens.  I'm not sure you're going to get a better answer than that.

There are a a few standard types of modules which are relevant to the question of splitting, though.  Namely, if $N$ is an [injective module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module) or if $L$ is a [projective module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module) then the sequence is guaranteed to split.

Also if $M$ is a [semisimple module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module), then the sequence must split.  This can happen completely independently of injectivity and projectivity.  For example, if you take a ring with a simple module $S_1$ that isn't injective and a simple module $S_2$ which isn't projective, then $0\to S_1\to S_1\oplus S_2\to S_2\to 0$ splits (obviously) but it certainly doesn't do so because of the reason of projectivity or injectivity mentioned above.